# Server-Side-Blazor with login through Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor app and want to create a login procedure for it. Therefore I know that I could scaffold and dedit the default MVC-pages to achive this.

On the other hand I have once read that it should also be possible to achive the same by using a controller for the login-process:

My Controller:

```
using BlazorTestAuthorisierung.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace BlazorTestAuthorisierung.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly SignInManager<Benutzer> _SignInManager;



        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody] Benutzer Benutzer)
        {
            var result = _SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Benutzer.Email, Benutzer.EingegebenesPasswort, false, lockoutOnFailure: false).Result;


            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                IActionResult response = Ok(new { result = "" });
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                IActionResult response = Unauthorized(new { result=""});
                return response;
            }
        }
           

        public LoginController(SignInManager<Benutzer> signInManager)
        {
            _SignInManager = signInManager;
        }
       
    }
}
```

And my blazor login

```
<EditForm Model=@LoginBenutzer OnValidSubmit="@OnLoginClick">
    <InputText @bind-Value="LoginBenutzer.Email" />
    <InputText @bind-Value="LoginBenutzer.EingegebenesPasswort" />
    <button type="submit">
        Anmelden
    </button>
</EditForm>

<AuthorizeView Roles=Administrator>
    <Authorized>
        Admin
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code{
    private Benutzer LoginBenutzer = new Benutzer() {
            Email = "",
            EingegebenesPasswort = ""
    };

    private async Task OnLoginClick()
    {

        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LoginBenutzer);
        var stringContent = new StringContent(serialized, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var result = await http.PostAsync($"{navigationManager.BaseUri}api/Login", stringContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
   
    }
    }
```

The login-result showed that the login succeeded. Nevertheless when I go back to my Blazor app it still doesn't recognises that the user is logged in, because it is always displaying "Not logged in".

```
<AuthorizeView>

    <Authorized>
        Logged in
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        Not logged in
    </NotAuthorized>

</AuthorizeView>
```

I think that the state of the controller doesn't comes back to the blazor circle after authorization.

Any help how to achive my goal or if it is not possible at all, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. My current workaround is to scaffold the included mvc-pages.